# concatenate a string to a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, jscript

How would I include this promise within a string?

Let's say I have

```
function BaseUrl() {        
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { return some_string;
  });
}
```

I am using the above function (`BaseUrl()`) below:

```
function FirstChar() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { return BaseUrl() + "some/suffix";
  });
}
```

**How do I concatenate a string to a promise?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would `resolve`it

```
function FirstChar() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { resolve(BaseUrl() + "some/suffix");
  });
}
```

**Edit**
You can also shorten it up to this

```
function FirstChar() {
    return Promise.resolve(BaseUrl() + "some/suffix");
  });
}
```

**Edit 2nd**
Using value of first promise in the second promise. see [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```
function BaseUrl() {        
    return Promise.resolve(some_string);
}

// using async await
async function FirstChar() {
    const baseurl = await BaseUrl()
    return Promise.resolve(baseurl + "some/suffix";
}
```

Comment: what if you had BaseUrl1() and BaseUrl2() and you needed to ```return BaseUrl1()+BaseUrl2()+'some string';``` ?

Comment: would you simply do ```return resolve(BaseUrl1()) + resolve(BaseUrl2()) + "some/suffix");```?

Comment: no you would not be returning anything, in [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) you `resolve` and `reject`. So you would `resolve( BaseUrl1() + BaseUrl2() + "some/suffix"`

Comment: thank you very much, what would be the syntax if you do something like ```PromiseA(PromiseB)()``` -- you are passing 1 promise into another promise - in this case where/when/how do we resolve this?

Comment: i edited my answer, is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make much sense to use a `Promise` just to return a string, but if you wanted to, you would have to pass the string (and the concatenated string) into each `resolve`:

```js
function BaseUrl() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve('some_string');
  });
}

function FirstChar() {
  return BaseUrl()
    .then(baseUrlStr => {
      return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        resolve(baseUrlStr + "some/suffix");
      });
    })
}

FirstChar().then(fullURL => console.log('got ' + fullURL))
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea why your second function is called `FirstChar`... ignoring that, do you mean

```
function FirstChar(baseUrlPromise) {
  return baseUrlPromise.then(baseUrl => baseUrl + "some/suffix");
}
```

or

```
function FirstChar() {
  return BaseUrl().then(baseUrl => baseUrl + "some/suffix");
}
```

b/c the return type of those *are* a (string) Promise.